# Connecting a Device as a USB Device with STM32 as a USB Host

Tags: android, stm32

I want to connect the Android device as a USB Device to an STM32 board which acts as a host device.

My application code for Android looks like:

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.usb_connection">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

So when I am trying to get the connected USB device details, the USB Device list is always null :

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
Map<String,UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
```

Again, I also tried to get the accessory list, the USB accessory list is also null.

```
UsbAccessory[] accessoryList = manager.getAccessoryList();
```

Then tried **ADB commands** to connect the device. I have created a Desktop application in JAVA to run ADB command and its working fine. But when I tried run ADB command from my Android App, it's giving **java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [ ADB, pull , ...] Working Directory: null Environment: null**.

STM32 firmware is written in C.

Please help me I am stuck for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do on the STM32 side? You need to first connect to the Android device over USB and determine (on the STM32 side) whether the Android device is in AOA mode (by checking the Vendor and Product ID). If it's not, you need to send some USB requests that will toggle it (I've included the STM32 USBH library call name):

USBH_GetProtocol Version
USBH_SetString 0 manufacturer name
USBH_SetString 1 model name
USBH_SetString 2 description
USBH_SetString 3 version
USBH_SetString 4 URI
USBH_SetString 5 serial number
Start Accessory

You can see that process explained in more detail here:
https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/aoa#attempt-to-start-in-accessory-mode

Once you've done that, you'll disconnect from the USB device (it will reset the connection) and you'll need to redo the enumeration process. This time, the Vendor and Product ID should be that of an AOA device (0x18D1 & 0x2D00/1). Now you can just connect to it and use a fairly standard USBH_CDC communication process, with a few caveats. When you try to find the interface (in your interface init function), your subclass is 0xFF and your protocol is going to be 0x00).

It took me a while to get everything communicating properly, so having a usb logic analyzer is a really handy tool to make sure things are communicating properly.

Here are some other resources for getting the Android device to communicate once the STM32 is doing things correctly.

https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/aoa2
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html#manifest